# Child's dataSource methods not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I've a parent UITableViewController object named ObjectA and a derived ObjectB.

**MY GOAL:**
Override cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to just change cells appearance

ObjectA methods are called correctly so:

- numberOfRowsInSection: called in **parent, OK**
- numberOfSectionsInTableView: called in **parent, OK**
- cellForRowAtIndexPath: called in **parent, WRONG**

this is what i did:

```
/**
 * ObjectA
 */

@interface ObjectA : UITableViewController

@end

@implementation ObjectA

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return list.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /* Layout by ObjectA rules */
}

@end

/**
 * ObjectB
 */

@interface ObjectB : ObjectA

@end

@implementation ObjectB

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /* Layout by ObjectB rules */

    NOT CALLED
}

@end
```

**EDIT:**

Object are allocated programmatically so there aren't problem related to IB declarations.

**EDIT2:**

**MY CODE IS BUGGY... I WROTE A TEST PROJECT AND EVERYTHING WORKS AS EXPECTED** ... sorry

```
/**
 * ObjectA
 */

@interface ObjectA : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *list;
}
-(void)setList: (NSArray *)l;
@end

@implementation ObjectA

-(void)setList: (NSArray *)l {
    list = l;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return list.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end

/**
 * ObjectB
 */

@interface ObjectB : ObjectA

@end

@implementation ObjectB

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"child";
    return cell;
}

@end

/**
 * View controller
 */

@interface ViewController() {
    NSArray *list;
    ObjectA *obj;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    list = @[@"test1", @"test2", @"test3", @"test4", @"test5"];
    obj = [[ObjectB alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    obj.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:obj.view];

    [obj setList:list];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by wrong?

Comment: the expected result was: cellForRowAtIndexPath: called in CHILD, OK

Answer (score 0):

<s>Overide in ObjectB:</s>

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}
```

Works for me:

```
ObjectB *objA = [[ObjectB alloc] init];
objA.list = @[@"1"];
[self presentViewController:objA animated:YES completion:nil];
```